# Difference between こと、もの and やつ

Tags: grammar, usage

I am trying to understand the following clearly:

1. 私のこと
2. 私のもの
3. 私のやつ

When someone is talking about us, we can use こと.

> いいえ、それは私のことではないです
>
> No, that is not something related to me.

やつ is used when we talk about something physical like a bag, book, etc

> 例 これはあなたの財布ですか？ いいえ、私のやつではないです。

I am not sure on how to use わたしのもの

Could someone clarify ?

Comment: Might be a step on the way: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2102/what-is-the-%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8-in-sentences-such-as-%E3%81%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%9F%E3%81%AE%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8C%E5%A5%BD%E3%81%8D%E3%81%A0

Comment: The meaning of それは私のことではない is more like “That is not (about) me” than “That is not something related to me.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where did you see 「いいえ、私のやつではないです。」?  Almost no one would say that in real life because  私のやつ is collocationally constrained.  やつ sounds fairly slangy and mannish, so it does not sound natural to combine it with 私.  One will, however, occasionally hear オレのやつ or even ボクのやつ, both meaning "mine" when both the speaker and listener know exactly what item they are talking about.

Native speakers will just use 私の without a noun following it since 私の, in this particular context, already means "mine" instead of "my".

「私のではありません。」 = "It is not mine."  More literally, "It is not my belonging."

In the sentence above, the 私の part can be replaced with 私のもの but just using 私の would be a more natural choice for us native speakers.  もの may be added when wanting to emphasize that the item belongs to no one but to you yourself.

Answer (score -1):

もの： physical thing/object, like a book.
こと： non physical thing, like a fact or an idea.
やつ：physical thing or person. (familiar)

私のこと： me/things related to me.
私のもの/私のやつ： my property.

Comment: 私のこと often just means "me".

Comment: `私のこと often just means "me".`  [Here's the post](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2102/78) on that in case anyone's looking for it.

Comment: There is also the case that もの may refer to one of two separate words: 物, which is equivalent to 'a thing'. And 者, which is a slightly formal version of 人, which means 'a person'.