# How do the two が in もう止まらない　あなたがあなたのことが恋しい work?

Tags: translation, meaning

The following lyrics are from [a song called "YOU"](http://www.jtw.zaq.ne.jp/animesong/a/aquarian/you.html):

> "もう止まらない　あなたがあなたのことが恋しい"
>   *Mou tomaranai　 anata ga anata no koto ga koishii*

I know that "mou tomaranai" = "no longer stops" and "anata no koto ga koishii" = "miss/long for you" but that "ga" in the middle throws me off. It looks like it's saying "You miss the you that won't stop anymore", but that doesn't make sense to me given the rest of the context.

Any ideas?

Comment: Related question (not about the main point of the current question, but about こと in the quotation): [What is the こと in sentences such as あなたのことが好きだ?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2102)

Answer (score 6):

あなたが = あなたのことが

It's repeated for emphasis.

I think it's like... I can't stop (this feeling) anymore, I miss you, I really miss you.

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping that was the case, otherwise it just wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: Is there generally a pause between the two phrases (i.e. あなたが、あなたのことが恋しい)? Or is this all just run together?

Comment: @rintaun はい、普通は「もう止まらない。あなたが、あなたのことが恋しい。」と書くと思います。

Comment: @rintaun [As we discussed in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12111028#12111028), these are actually [song lyrics](http://www.jtw.zaq.ne.jp/animesong/a/aquarian/you.html).  For some reason, lyrics aren't usually written with punctuation, so the comma is left out.

Answer (score 1):

A native speaker told me it's a blend of あなたが恋しい and あなたのことが恋しい. She was even kind enough to translate it:

> I miss you, [everything] about you.

(You need the *everything* to make it make sense in English.)

Comment: Not true.  It is just customary to insert こと in saying you like/dislike/miss someone.  You DO NOT need to translate the こと part.  "Everything" may be implied but certainly not said.

Comment: I didn't translate the こと. I just added "everything" because the structure of English demands it.