# (Person's name) + 君の事

Tags: grammar

I came across the following sentence and I'm having troubles understanding the grammar:

> …一条君の事好きだった…

`一条` stands for the person's name. That being said, I understand `君` is a personal pronoun like `you`, as for the phrase `君の事` means something like "yourself" or "the real you".

What I don't get is the gramatics behind adding the person's name followed by a pronoun that refers to that person: `一条君の事`. Maybe it has to do with the fact that there is no `は` or `が` particle to denote topic/subject?

Comment: Enjoying us some Nisekoi, are we?

Comment: hahaha yeap, pretty good show

Comment: I think this use of こと is usually written in kana.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

君 when applied to person's name is not "きみ" but is "くん", which is honorific suffix for boys.
の事 is hard to translate directly, but basically it means "someone's being" (sorry if this is not the best translation).
好きだった is quite obvious.

So we get: "I used to like (love) mr. Ichijo".

Comment: 「のこと」 has been discussed previously: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2102/what-is-the-%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8-in-sentences-such-as-%E3%81%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%9F%E3%81%AE%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8C%E5%A5%BD%E3%81%8D%E3%81%A0

Answer (score 6):

**[君]{きみ} vs. [君]{くん}**

> 1) 君 is read **きみ** in:「一条、君の事好きだった。」
>
> 2) 君 is read **くん** in:「一条君の事好きだった。」

In Sentence #1, 「[君]{きみ}」 is a second-person pronoun.

In Sentence #2, 「[君]{くん}」 is a friendly honorific mostly for boys or those who are lower in status than you.

Sentence #1 can only mean ***one*** thing: "I liked you, Ichijou."

Sentence #2 can mean ***two completely different*** things: "I liked you, Ichijou." ***and*** "I liked Ichijou."

Which one Sentence #2 means depends on the context.  I want to point out that, unlike in English, we often use the person's name (plus an honorific) as a kind of a "second-person pronoun" when speaking directly to that  person.