# Trying to understand 私のこと in this sentence

Tags: grammar

According to a tweet from @real_eikaiwa, the following sentence:

> こんなに私のこと笑わせてくれる人なかなかいないって思ってる！

Translates to:

> "I don't think I've ever met anyone that made me laugh so much!"

But this doesn't sound right to me. To me, 「私のこと笑わせてくれる人」sounds like "someone who lets me laugh about myself". My translation would be rather:

> "I think there aren't that many people who let/make me laugh at myself this much!"

What do you guys think?

Comment: No, the original translation is correct.I think this thread gives good insight into のこと things: [What is the こと in sentences such as あなたのことが好きだ?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2102/what-is-the-こと-in-sentences-such-as-あなたのことが好きだ)

Comment: 私のこと just makes the sentence softer than 私を
there is no difference in the sense

Comment: Thanks @Rilakkuma I read through that entire post, but though I now understand the meaning better of 「あなたのこと」etc in terms of 好き、考える、覚える、and other such verbs, I'm still stuck on this one.

Comment: @WKx Thanks that's what I'll be treating it as... and waiting to see if I find any other examples.

Comment: @GavNewalkar this one works identically. 笑わせる is "make (someone) laugh". In this case it is same verb like 考える or 覚える. 私のこと覚える - remember me, 私のこと笑わせる - make me laugh.

Answer (score 0):

```
こんなに私のこと笑わせてくれる人なかなかいない[-]って思ってる[+]！
```

actually translates more accurately to

```
"I think[+] there's not[-] a person that 
 makes (or lets) me laugh 
 this much (or as much as ___ [you, him, her])"
```

Doesn't exactly roll off the tongue, though ;)

As  WKx said in the comments

```
 私のこと just makes the sentence softer than 私を there is no difference in the sense
```