# Understanding the meaning of a sentence

Tags: translation

わたし、かずさのことを愛してる。

I think it means "I love Kazusa". を愛してる would be the love part but I'd like to know if I'm missing something relevant.

Comment: related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2102/9831

Comment: You seem to be understanding the sentence fine. The only thing that we don't know if you understood correctly is のこと, which discussed in the question http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2102/1628. If you have a more precise question, please edit your question. (This will queue it for reopening.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what it means and you are not missing anything relevant.
I don't know why you thought you might be missing something relevant, but considering this is a sentence that only contains 3-4 words, there is not place for much misunderstanding.

わたし、-> I

かずさのこと -> About Kazusa

を愛してる -> Love

Comment: To your understanding is there a difference between I love kazusa and I love about Kazusa?

Comment: `only contains 3-4 words`>> Hm? That sentence consists of 8 words or so, no?

Comment: @Thebest no, it means the same.

Comment: @Shoko depends on how you see it. I consider 愛する as 1 word, and I don't consider の and を as words. I am aware that this is quite debatable.