# What is the difference between Verb+ときです and Verb+ときのことです?

Tags: grammar

Why is のこと used in the sentence below?

Or more specifically, what is the difference between V-ときです and V-ときのことです?

> むかし、むかし、桶屋で働く若者が桶にする竹を切っていた時**のこと**です。

Answer (score 5):

> 桶にする竹を切っていた時

Would refer to the time he cut the bamboo.

> 桶にする竹を切っていた時のこと

Refers to the things (こと) that happened during the time he cut the bamboo.

Answer (score 2):

- V-ときです: It happened when he was sawing a bamboo trunk.
- V-ときのことです: It was the event that happened when he was sawing a bamboo trunk.

The former one pays attention to the time, while the latter one pays attention to the event.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to help a lot in answering your question: [What is the こと in sentences such as あなたのことが好きだ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2102).

The selected answer explains how こと or 事【こと】 can be used in a few significantly different ways:

- to encompass the things around an object/concept (i.e. "about"), like your sentence does --

  > 時のこと (the event... / the thing(s) that happened when...)
- to simply mean "thing"
- > to add a layer of indirectness