# 「～について説明する」と「～を説明する」は　どう違いますか？

Tags: word-usage

「～について説明する」と「～を説明する」は　どう違いますか？　私はベトナム人ですので日本語で説明したら良かったです。英語で説明したらちょっと難しいですが頑張ります。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ようこそ、ジャパニーズ・ランゲージ・スタック・エクスチェンジへ！概{おおむ}ねnarutoさんの、この質問 : [~を話す to mean talk about? Confusion](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/55377/%e3%82%92%e8%a9%b1%e3%81%99-to-mean-talk-about-confusion) においての御回答とこの論文 : [テーマを示す複合助詞「について」と格助詞「を」](http://repository.tufs.ac.jp/bitstream/10108/20016/1/jlc033001.pdf) が参考になるかと思います。日本語が母国語の人は無意識に使い分けているかも知れませんが...。

Comment: なるほど、どうもありがとうございます　！