# How do I say "people like me"

Tags: english-to-japanese

It's for a daily affirmation. I don't mean people that behave like me which is what I keep getting when I search for a translation; I mean "people like me as a person". Do I just use 好き？

Comment: It is easy as pie to "translate" that to Japanese, but whether or not  Japanese-speakers would actually say/murmur that on a daily basis is a totally different matter.  It simply is not a very Japanese thing to say in the first place.

Comment: It's a personal affirmation that is only for me, so whether or not Japanese people would say it is not relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean you want to say something along the lines of "everyone loves me"? Then, yes, you can just use 好き and say 人々は私が好きです (literal), みんな(は)私のことが好きだ (more natural, see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2102/5010) for のこと), or such.

Comment: Yes, I think the second one is what I am after.