# Double checking my understanding of のことで

Tags: grammar

Would just like to check my understanding of お前の持ってる徽章のことで交渉がしたい

Am I correct that the のこと nominalizes "お前の持ってる徽章" and で is simply means 'with' for 交渉がしたい

"With the talisman you have - I want to negotiate"

Comment: Nominalization is not needed, since お前の持ってる徽章 is already a noun. I see this のこと after a noun quite often and I'm pretty sure they just use it when they want to say "about" as in "discuss about, negotiate about, think about" etc.

Comment: The で keeps irking me for some reason.

Is it grammatical to say お前の持ってる徽章のことを交渉したい

Comment: http://www.edewakaru.com/archives/15531056.html "grammar not on JLPT" lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This こと is not a nominalizer. Nominalization refers to turning a verb/adjective into a noun. It looks like this:

- 食べる to eat
- 食べる**こと** eating
- 青い blue
- 青い**こと** blueness

お前の持ってる徽章 is already a noun phrase, and it doesn't have to be nominalized. This ～のこと means "things about..." or "matter regarding...". Please see [What is the こと in sentences such as あなたのことが好きだ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2102/5010)

> お前の持ってる徽章**のことで**交渉がしたい。
> I want to negotiate with you **about/regarding** the insignia you have.