# Parsing the sentence: アイシャのこともラトレイア家やミリス神聖国の学校で何かと比べられて、常に下に見られて劣等感に苛まれていたことから嫌っていた。

Tags: grammar, parsing

> アイシャのこともラトレイア家やミリス神聖国の学校で何かと比べられて、常に下に見られて劣等感に苛まれていたことから嫌っていた。

How to combine the following components?

アイシャのことも -> Also Aisha's things (?)

ラトレイア家やミリス神聖国の学校で何かと比べられて、 -> and by being compared in one way or another in Holy Country's schools and Ratoreia

常に下に見られて -> by always being looked down (?)

劣等感に苛まれていた -> tortured by inferior complexity

ことから嫌っていた -> (Norun (ノルン), by context) hates because

Comment: Wait....maybe the entire ラトレイア家やミリス神聖国の学校で何かと比べられて、常に下に見られて劣等感に苛まれていたこと is a clause?

Comment: Then the full translation is "She hates Aisha's things because she is suffered from inferior complexity by always being looked down and being compared in one way or another in [those places]."

Comment: Could anyone confirm that?

Comment: Correct, except アイシャのこと doesn’t mean “Aisha’s things”. It refers to Aisha herself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the subject is [this character](https://seesaawiki.jp/musyo-ten/d/%a5%ce%a5%eb%a5%f3%a1%a6%a5%b0%a5%ec%a5%a4%a5%e9%a5%c3%a5%c8).

Regarding your first comment, it is correct. So without the clause, it is アイシャのことも嫌っていた, which means *(She) hated also Aisha (in addition to someone else)*. About the こと here, have a look at [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2102/45489).

As for the clause, こと is a nominalizer for the whole '(...比べられて、...下に見られて)劣等感に苛まれていた', から is literally *from* indicating reason. So that part translates literally as *from that she suffered from inferior complex, being compared (with Aisha) in ... and always being looked down on*.